# How can I repeat or reuse Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am making my first app game.

The pictures below are my app's activities, and this is the process of my app.

1. Player chooses the number of player
2. Each player receives his/her role one by one.

In my game, at maximum, 20 players can play the game.
However, I can't repeat ' 1st-Your Role is..., 2nd-Your role is..., 3rd-Your Role is.. ' thing 
20 times...

So I want to repeat and reuse my Activity as the number of players chosen. 
I want to repeat my Activity and only change 1st to 2nd and player's role. 
I googled for many hours, but I wasn't able to find the way...

I will be really grateful if someone answers my question
Thanks

[image: *emphasized text*]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be great if you can share what you code you have written, so people can help you by pointing at specific place you need to make changes.

Comment: You don't have to resuse the activity for this you can just change the textview to 2nd player on the click of a button after player 1's turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to give high level detailed explanation for what you should try to do.

1. You cannot reuse activities - There is concept called Fragment. You should probably use that. Now a days, almost everyone tries to make Single Activity apps with many fragments.
2. Even if you use fragments, you dont need to create 20 fragments to do your task.
3. You can have single activity ( MainActivity ) with 1 fragment (PlayerDetailsFrgament). Invoke this fragment onClick of ' Next/ Confirm ' button by sending data to fragment using intents OR reading the players number and role from your array or list whatever you have and then changing the UI.

So basically what you are explaining, you should be able to do that job with 1 Activity and 1 Fragment. You dont need 20 different activities for this.

I hope it helps